# O( log n! ) and O( (log n )! )

Tags: algorithm, logging, big-o

To find their relation I substituted `log n = x and log n! = n(log n)` so with base a , `O( log n! )` became `a^x(x)` and `(log n)!` became `x(x-1)(x-2)`....
now I think the first one has a higher growing speed. But can you help me to find their relation using big O of n^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually `x(x-1)(x-2)....` becomes `x^x + ...` because you have `x` scopes. This means that `O((log n)!)`has a higher growing speed.
2. Also, if `log(n) := x`, then `n = 2^x` and `n^2` will become `(2^x)^2 = 2^2x` which has lower growing speed than `x^x`

**Summary**

`O(log n!) < O(n^2) < O((log n)!)`